# Orcad Schematic Capture. Instances vs Occurrences

Tags: schematics, orcad

Using Orcad capture to create a multi-page hierarchical schematic I used the "Annotate..." option to renumber all parts. First set the them to "?" then incrementally update them.

However, after this when looking at part properties I realized that every single part in the schematic (not just the ones in the hierarchical pages) now had two different versions: the instance in white, and the occurrence in yellow.

Now every single change had to be done to both versions of the part, or I had to make sure that the corresponding occurrence field was deleted, so that it would default to the instance. You can see an example here: 
[image: Orcad Capture property editor]
In this case the part reference is different for the instance and the occurrence, while the PCB footprint in the occurrence is defaulting to the one in the instance.

This became very cumbersome and confusing very quickly. For example, copying a part and pasting it elsewhere, would generate a copy of the instance, not of the specific occurrence I was copying.

After many repetitions of "Annotate..." with different settings (and multiple errors while trying to generate a BOM) I found out that by going to every single occurrence and deleting the part reference field by hand, in most cases I could remove the occurrence, making cleanup easier. But I still had to fix a few more issues so that I could get a clean BOM.

My questions are:

1. What is the purpose of the "Occurrence" in non-hierarchical portions of the design?
2. How can I clean up these occurrences in the future, or how can I avoid them from reappearing?

Update: I am not sure why, but I again have undesired occurrences messing up part numbering. So I have to do yet another pass through the Annotate and cleanup cycle.

Related question: [Hierarchical designs in Orcad Capture](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/44856/orcad-issue-while-designing-schematics)

Comment: Take a look at https://community.cadence.com/cadence_blogs_8/b/pcb/posts/customer-support-recommended-understanding-instance-and-occurrence-modes-of-design-annotation-using-allegro-design-entry-cis to see if that helps.  You can also use the Accessories->Transfer Occ Prop to Instance command to get rid of differences.  Under Options->Preferences on the Misc tab you can select "preserve reference on copy" which can sometimes make things less confusing.

Comment: @crj11 That menu option does not work for me as I do have a true hierarchical design with component reuse (it is intended for simpler schematics). Even if there is a single schematic page that is being reused 4 times, and I would call that a simple hierarchy, it is still considered a "Complex hierarchy" for OrCad.

Comment: I agree that dealing with the Instances/Occurrences stuff in Orcad is often painful.  To more easily fix problems, you can select columns in the Orcad spreadsheet and paste them into Excel or an equivalent, fix them up there, and then copy them back.  You need to make sure that all of the occurrence lines are open so that they get copied.  You can add columns in the spreadsheet so that you can sort to isolate instance versus occurrence in order to edit them more easily.  You of course need to restore the correct  order before copying them back.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer some of #2 for you :)

You can remove Occurrences by clicking on the .DSN in the project tab and selecting

Design -> Remove Occurrence Properties

Be sure to have copies of your .DSN saved somewhere because there is no going back from this operation.

Comment: That will sure come in handy rather soon.